# How to display an element specific to an object in an array with ngIf

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I am trying to allow the end user the ability to edit a post they have created. I am displaying an array of posts to them using Angular `ngFor`. The content of the post has an `ngIf` which is toggled if the user wants to edit the post.

```
<div class="card-body">
  <p class="card-text" *ngIf="!showEditPost">{{ post.content }}</p>
  <div *ngIf="showEditPost">
    <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <textarea name="text-post" [(ngModel)]="post.content" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-2">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-light">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updatePost()">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is that the `showEditPost` variable is the same on every iteration of the `ngFor` array, which means that every single post will be editable when `showEditPost` is true.

My question is how do I edit a specific post without making every post editable at the same time.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can we see the `*ngFor` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you need to add a property named **`showEdit`** on each post object and then you can just do

```
<p class="card-text" *ngIf="!post.showEdit">{{ post.content }}</p>
```